# Pass Input to tensorflow lite model in Android

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow-lite

I have created a neural network that take numerical data as input and saved it as tensorflow lite model using python. 
I am trying to pass input to the model in Android. 
Shape of ndarray is 1*3

Sample of the input in python is as follows

```
np.array([[-0.276786765 ,8.41897583008  ,-0.0222015380859]])
```

But i do not know to create the same input in java to pass it to model.

I tried using nd4j library. But still not able to write the proper code to create the input which is required by the model.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#java), you can provide a 1x3 input using:

```
float[] innerInput = {-0.276786765 ,8.41897583008  ,-0.0222015380859
float[][] input = {innerInput};
interpreter.run(input, output);
```